# Simulating tab selection to open panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-tabs

I am working on a bootstrap website. I have a button that I click on one pageA to an href tab on pageB. I want to be able to click on the button on pageA and open the tab and the connected panel on pageB.
**Here is what I have researched and tried:**

1. jQueryUi tabs to set a specific tab to active

   `$('#learn2').click(function(){
   $('#tactical-tab').tabs('select', 4);
   });`
2. jQuery triggers to simulate an event
   `$('#learn2').click(function(){
   $('#tactical-tab').trigger('click');
   });`
3. Adding a class via css to set tab to active
   `$('#learn2').click(function(){
   $('#tactical-tab').addClass(".ui-tabs-active");
   });`

**Here is some code for the button.**
    `<h4><a href="services.html#tactical-tab" class="btn btn-default learn-more"                     id="learn2">Learn More</a></h4>`

**Here is some code for the tabs and tab-panels**
**Tabs**
    `<div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <a href="#service-five" id="tactical-tab"> Tactical Transparency</a>
                </li>
           </ul>`
**Panel**
`<div id="service-five">
                <h4>Tactical Transparency</h4>
                <p>Sample paragraph</p>
            </div>`

Any help or input would be appreciated as I am not sure where the next place to research would be or if I am just missing something.

Comment: So you want to click a link on page A.html and open a specified tab on page B.html? Is this correct?

Comment: @mark that is correct

Comment: Just an update: I wrapped the link from tabs in a button to try and trigger an event. I am working on that now.  Iwould love input from anyone with a experience